# Both if / else statements being triggered

Tags: javascript

```
var game = "play"
var movie = "watch"
var userInput = prompt ("What do you want to do?"); {
  if (userInput === game) {
    if(Math.random <= 0.5) {
      console.log("play some mc")
    } else {
      console.log ("get some bf3 in ya")
    }
  }
  else (userInput === movie); {
    if (Math.random <= 0.5) {
      console.log("netflix is the way to go")
    } else {
      console.log("bit of youtube wouldnt hurt")
    }
  }
}
```

When I enter 'play', both statements are triggered.

However, if I enter 'watch', only the else statement is executed, as intended.

Comment: remove else and add else if...

Answer (score 3):

Else doesn't take a condition.

In other words, in your code where it says

```
else (userInput === movie);
```

the non-sensical statement `userInput === movie;` is evaluated, and that's the end of the 'else' part.

Then the rest of the code, between curly braces, is evaluated/run.

So either you make this an `else if` statement - and remove the semicolon - or remove the "condition" if you want the rest of the code to be run no matter what.

---

See [this JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/BrechtDeMan/4doqd1un/) (slightly modified to allow playing around with it).

```
var game = "play"
var movie = "watch"
var userInput = prompt ("What do you want to do?"); {
  if (userInput === game) {
    if(Math.random <= 0.5) {
     document.getElementById("result").textContent = "play some mc";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("result").textContent = "get some bf3 in ya";
    }
  }
  else if (userInput === movie) {
    if (Math.random <= 0.5) {
      document.getElementById("result").textContent =  "netflix is the way to go";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("result").textContent = "bit of youtube wouldnt hurt";
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the part

```
else (userInput === movie); {
```

to

```
else if (userInput === movie) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems with the `else` part of your statement. First, since you left out the `if` of the `else if`, the condition in parentheses is not being used as a test; it's simply being evaluated as a statement. This is reinforced by the semicolon after the closing parenthesis. The code in braces following the `else` is simply being evaluated as a code block, after the `if/else` statement finishes. So instead of this:

```
else (userInput === movie); {
```

you really need this:

```
else if (userInput === movie) {
```

Answer (score -1):

You're missing the `if` statement in your outer else statement. `If (...) else` statement will not evaluate any criteria provided in the brackets. Whereas `If (...) else if (...)` will.

[More on if...else statement.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

So replace

`else (userInput === movie); {`

with

`else if (userInput === movie) {`

Below is fixed code snippet with the changes.

```js
var game = "play"
var movie = "watch"
var userInput = prompt("What do you want to do?"); {
    if (userInput === game) {
        if (Math.random <= 0.5) {
            console.log("play some mc")
        } else {
            console.log("get some bf3 in ya")
        }
    } else if (userInput === movie) {
        if (Math.random <= 0.5) {
            console.log("netflix is the way to go")
        } else {
            console.log("bit of youtube wouldnt hurt")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would love to know why the downvote :)